# The 2nd total derivative (Hessian) of a composite function -Version 2

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> Let $f\in C^2(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R)$ and
>
> $Df:A\subset\mathbb R^n\to L(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R)$ so that $Df_x:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ is $f$'s total derivative at $x\in\mathbb R^n$.
>
> Let $f$'s Hessian at the point $x$ be $Hf_x: \mathbb R^n \times  \mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$, defined (as a bilinear form) by  $$Hf_x(x_1,x_2)=[[D(Df)_x] (x_2)](x_1).$$    Further, let $a\in\mathbb R^n$ and define $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ by $$g(t)=f(a+xt).$$

Claim: $$g''(t)=Hf_{a+xt}(x,x).$$

My attempt at proving the claim:

$g$'s Hessian matrix is $Hg_t=g''(t)$.

Therefore $$x^Tg''(t)x=x^THg_tx$$ $$=x^THf_{a+tx}x$$$$=Hf_{a+xt}(x,x).$$ I.e.,
$$||x||^2g''(t)=Hf_{a+xt}(x,x).$$

Is my derivation or the given claim wrong?